# Mathematical formulation of expanding a matrix

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to write down expanding a matrix as an equation, my thought is i have to break it up into odd and even indexes but I'm a little stuck, essentially what I want to write as an equation is:

$$M = \begin{bmatrix}
    a       & b \\
    c       & d \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$N = \begin{bmatrix}
    a       & a & b & b \\
    a       & a & b & b \\
    c       & c & d & d \\
    c       & c & d & d \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I want to write Matrix N in terms of matrix M, so i'm thinking I can break it down into:

$$N = \begin{cases} ?? & \mbox{if } i,j\mbox{ is even} \\ ?? & \mbox{if } i,j\mbox{ is odd} \end{cases}$$

but i'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

One way to write N in terms of M would be

$N[i,j] = M[\lfloor\frac{i}{2}\rfloor,\lfloor\frac{j}{2}\rfloor]$

But I really don't understand by what you mean by separating it into odd, even indexes.